# Why my Sonar Jenkins job never becomes unstable, even with test failures?

Tags: unit-testing, maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I have a job in Jenkins that is run every night. The tasks executed during this build are: compilation, unit tests, integration tests (which are only JUnit tests which are longer than "real unit tests" to execute), and Sonar quality analysis.

When a test fails, the job is however considered as successfull and thus, no email is sent to notify this failure.

The Maven command used is `mvn clean install sonar:sonar`. Removing the `install` goal does not change anything.

What is wrong with that?

Is there a way to get the expected behavior (i.e. having an unstable build when a test failed) with only one Jenkins job, or should I create two jobs, one for the whole "Java part" (compile, unit test and integration tests), and one for the Sonar analysis?

We are using Maven 2.0.9, Java 1.6, Sonar 2.8, Jenkins 1.413.

Comment: are you defining -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true anywhere?

Comment: @oers Not at all. The exact Maven command is `mvn -U -up -e clean install -Dsonar.branch=XXX --settings C:\xxx\jenkins-setting.xml`

Comment: Jenkins seems to set that property: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004912/hudson-build-successful-with-unit-test-failures

Comment: @oers Ok, with this property (`-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false`), when there is a test failure, the build stops, and I don't want that, as even with test failures, it should analyse the project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins seems to set that property: [Hudson build successful with unit test failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004912/hudson-build-successful-with-unit-test-failures)

With the property (-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false), when there is a test failure, the build stops.

There is a [jenkins plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Hudson+and+Jenkins+Plugin) for sonar: 
That seems to analyze even if Tests fails: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-461

In my sonar installation, I run the tests seperate from sonar and reuse the junit/surefire reports. That way I can control the tests independently from sonar.

Comment: I am indeed not sure that I can only have one Jenkins job to do everything. Setting the property `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore` to `false` will not help me, as it will stop the compilation and test on the first module with error. And as I am working with multi-modules project, it will not work on others modules...

Comment: I finally succeed in using the Sonar Jenkins plugin (there was a bug with Maven 2.0.9 and this plugin, which ignores my `--settings` parameter) and the status is now correctly handled by Jenkins.