# FoneMonkey test crash during Jenkins run

Tags: ios, testing, automated-tests, jenkins

I use FoneMonkey + Jenkins for automated iOS test. I ask FoneMonkey to generate XML reports (`FM_ENABLE_XML_REPORT` - set to TRUE) and run it with [waxsim](https://github.com/square/waxsim). Today I find out that when app crashes (ie due to `NSInvalidArgumentException`) the xml report is not generated. And then in Jenkis I see 100% passing (I use standard JUNIT plugin), with its obviously not true.

The only ways to spot this is to:
a) analyse Jenkins console log (ie looking for `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception`)
b) spot that in Jenkins report the number of run test is lower then perviously (that's how my teammates spotted the problem).

I know that I can use Jenkins Text Finder plugin for solution a), but I would like to have accurate reports.

Is there any way to achieve it? If no, is FoneMonkey anything useful?

Answer (score -1):

If executing a tool fails (indicated by a non-zero exit code), Jenkins detects this and marks the build as failed.  If the tools are broken, there's not much Jenkins can do to help.

For your situation, I see several possibilities:

- FoneMonkey should be fixed to return a non-zero exit code when the app under test crashes
- FoneMonkey should be fixed to always output XML, even when the app under test crashes
- You could write a custom FoneMonkey-output-to-JUnit-parser rather than relying on FoneMonkey (e.g. similar projects exist for parsing Android test runner output)

Comment: Thanks but it's not so easy. 1. FoneMonkey is just lib added to app so  it can return exit code to host (It's run on waxsim). 2. Since it's lib it can't do anything (i.e. genera report) when app crashes. 3. I know that on android it's instrumentation/test runner etc, on iOS there isn't. So only way is to pars whole log (like parsing logcat in android).

Comment: Ah, you have to embed it? That doesn't sound so great. But it's still surely a bug if the test runner doesn't return a non-zero output in case of app failure. Anyway, if FoneMonkey can't generate a report if the app crashes, how does the report get generated at the end of the build? Can you integrate something like BPOCUnitXMLReporter instead of relying on FoneMonkey's output? Have you filed a bug on their bug tracker asking about these problems? What stops you from parsing the log output?

Comment: I think BPOCUnitXMLReporter works only with OCUnit tests. Regarding returning non-zero exit code - I'm not sure if this is the best approach when running test for example when ruing JUnit test Jenkins default behaviour is only marking build as unstable not failed - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004912/hudson-build-successful-with-unit-test-failures. It's also bad since it will only run until first fail and I would like to run all tests and have report that contains all crashes (I restart waxim for each test - I use env variable to tell FoneMonkey which test it should run).

Comment: And yes, I will probably end with console parsing, but I would like to check if this is only way since it's strange that FoneMonkey is so popular and I couldn't find similar problem - maybe I'm doing something wrong...