# Maven test BuildErrorException

Tags: maven

If I have a `BuildErrorException` due to a compile error, Maven still passes the build. Is there an argument I can pass in to fail the build if there are ANY exceptions? Thanks.

Stack trace:

```
org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:715)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
```

Comment: `-ff,--fail-fast` will fail a multi-module build on the first failing module, but it sounds like you have a single module build that's not failing on compile problems. That's strange, can you provide more information about the exception that's being produced?

Comment: There are a number of unit tests that run and pass and in a separate module integration tests are run. These integration tests sometimes have compile errors. Here's the stack trace:

Comment: Is the `maven.test.failure.ignore=false` set, or are you using hudson (which sets it)? This is the only way I know of for preventing test issues from failing the build.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004912/hudson-build-successful-with-unit-test-failures) should provide the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your pom.xml:

```
<project>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.failOnError>true</maven.compiler.failOnError>
    </properties>
```

Or add to your command line when launching maven

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.compiler.failOnError=true
```

[This appears to work as of maven-compiler-plugin version 2.0.2.](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-48)

Comment: Don't I want `failOnError` to be `true`?

Comment: This will do the opposite to OP's question.